# The tag [os-agnostic] is meaningless

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[os-agnostic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/os-agnostic) is a classic example of a meta-tag. It doesn't provide any meaningful information and should be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions. Where appropriate, more descriptive tags have been added in its place.

Answer (score -4):

I see this one as an OS tag replacement rather than a meta tag.  It's for questions in which the specific OS often makes a difference but for that particular issue, it doesn't, and it conveys that fact.

It could be a situation where a problem is known to be across all platforms on which an application runs, so it is relevant to include this as diagnostic information.  Another situation is where someone has access to every major OS, is looking for a solution to a problem, and isn't particular about the platform.  I answered a question like that, which got closed, and one of the stated issues (in comments), was that a specific OS wasn't specified.

The tag replaces inclusion of every possible OS tag.  It could be renamed [any-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/any-os).  However, it should get a wiki excerpt clarifying that it should be used only for questions that are exceptions to the usual relevance of a specific OS.  I imagine that lacking such a definition, past usage of the tag wandered from a legitimate purpose.

Comment: That's just it, do we **really** need an [os-agnostic] or [any-os] tag? If the question/problem is generic enough to not be OS-specific, then either we're going to get answers which aren't OS-specific, or which are that state "On Windows do X, on Mac do Y". Sorry, I don't see what value this tag adds

Comment: It doesn't enhance the ability for someone to find a question about it

Comment: @CanadianLuke - Excellent.  You nailed it.